# Using SQL Objects in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please help to resolve this. 
Getting the below error while executing the function

> [Error] ORA-00947 (7: 17): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ty_1 AS OBJECT (fn VARCHAR2(100),
                                       sl NUMBER,
                                       hd DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_RET_COL
  RETURN ty_1
AS
  obj_ty_1 ty_1;
  BEGIN

    SELECT
      first_name,
      salary,
      hire_date
    INTO obj_ty_1
    FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = 100;

  END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an object of the type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_RET_COL RETURN TY_1
AS
  OBJ_TY_1     TY_1; 
BEGIN
  SELECT TY_1(FIRST_NAME,SALARY,HIRE_DATE)
  INTO OBJ_TY_1
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 100;
END;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_RET_COL RETURN TY_1
AS
  OBJ_TY_1     TY_1 := TY_1(null,null,null); 
BEGIN
  SELECT FIRST_NAME,SALARY,HIRE_DATE
  INTO OBJ_TY_1.FN, OBJ_TY_1.SL, OBJ_TY_1.HD
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 100;
END;
```

both will work.

Please, see the difference of the second example with another answer: it has initialized object.

Exactly your error is about different amounts of `select` and `into` clauses columns

Comment: +1 but please correct mistyped `:= OBJ_TY_1(` to `:= TY_1(` and same thing in `select` in first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_RET_COL RETURN TY_1 AS
   OBJ_TY_1 TY_1 := TY_1(null, null, null); 
BEGIN
   SELECT FIRST_NAME,SALARY,HIRE_DATE
     INTO OBJ_TY_1.FN, OBJ_TY_1.SL, OBJ_TY_1.HD
     FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 100;
   return OBJ_TY_1;
END;
```

Comment: and seems not correct because the object is not initialized yet